# Why did Allanon want to live and changed his mind all of a sudden to die?

Tags: character, analysis, the-shannara-chronicles

In [The Shannara Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1051220/), around episode 5-6. The druid (**Allanon**) gets wounded by the 'special' sword obtained by the kings son. He lies in his druid cave, *bleeding to death*.

> Then he starts casting some enchantments asking the Fire to heal him because he doesn't want to die. The fire glows... he keeps continues the spell talking about Earth... then the fire stops glowing. The screen hops to another scene and when you get back to Allanon, he sees his **master** and he's saying he's ready to leave the earth and join him in the afterlife.

**Q**: What was the thought about Allanon here? First he wants to live and all of a sudden he changes his mind?

Comment: I think the impression is: he's done this a *lot*.  Over and over and over again.  The druid is starting the ritual out of habit, but he's a wee bit tired of his gig.